# Possible solution for ''constraint specification not allowed here'' in Oracle live

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know what is causing this problem. Can anybody help me find it out? Also Oracle live doesn't specify which line is causing the problem.

```
create table EMP (
    EMPNO number(4),
    ENAME varchar2(10),
    EJOB varchar2(9) constraint def_job default 'CLRK',
    MGR_ID number(4) constraint supervisor references EMPNO,
    BIRTH_DATE date,
    SAL number(7,2) constraint salCheck check(SAL > 20000) constraint defSal default 20001,
    COMM number(7,2) constraint defComm default 1000,
    DEPTNO varchar2(3) constraint deptFk references DPT(DNO),
    PRJ_ID varchar2(9) constraint defa_prjID default 'P1', 
    DATE_OF_JOIN date,
    
    constraint pri_ky primary key(EMPNO)
);
```

Error: ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Comment: Why does the `SAL number(7,2)` line have two constraints?

Comment: that was mentioned in the assignment to have a default value and salary greater than 20000.

Comment: `default<value>` is not a valid constraint specification (and logically, what does such constraint really constraint?). Please, check the documentation about `create table` and especially [inline constraint definition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE). Then correct your query and ask a question about the issue you cannot resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default value is not a constraint, so for example

```
constraint def_job default 'CLRK'
```

should just be

```
default 'CLRK'
```

Also, constraints need to reference a table and optionally a unique column, so

```
constraint supervisor references EMPNO
```

should be

```
constraint supervisor references emp(empno)
```

It's good practice, or at least a good idea, not to specify a datatype for foreign keys, allowing them to inherit from the parent column.

This works (after creating a `dept` table):

```
create table dpt (dno integer primary key);

create table emp (
    empno           number(4) constraint pri_ky primary key,
    ename           varchar2(10),
    ejob            varchar2(9) default 'CLRK',
    mgr_id          constraint supervisor references emp(empno),
    birth_date      date,
    sal             number(7,2) default 20001 constraint salcheck check(sal > 20000),
    comm            number(7,2) default 1000,
    deptno          constraint deptfk references dpt(dno),
    prj_id          varchar2(9) default 'P1', 
    date_of_join    date
);
```

Comment: But when 'default' value added after creation of table, SQL allows the user to specify constraint name to default value, also sites like w3school mentioned 'default' as a constraint. I just confused here a bit.

Comment: @BIjoyDas If you have a link to a site suggesting this, I’d be interested in seeing it. A default isn’t a constraint and you can’t name it, so something must have got mixed up somewhere.

Comment: @BIjoyDas Don't use w3schools as it is far to easy to read documentation for the wrong database. If you want to find out what is allowed in an Oracle database then use [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877).

Comment: I didn't mean to rude, just a bit perplexed. here is the link:- https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_default.asp

Comment: @BIjoyDas Look at the solutions for the different databases on that page - you need to read the Oracle one and not the SQL Server one. Or even better, don't use w3schools.

Comment: @BIjoyDas thanks for the link, that's interesting. I am a bit surprised that MS SQL Server syntax treats defaults as constraints even though they don't constrain anything, and it's hard to see where the name could be useful as there can never be a constraint violation error message, but hey, that's weird non-Oracle syntax for you :)